# Getting SSAO shader working with SkinnedMesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've been attempting to get the SSAO post-processing shader to work with the latest (r77) version of three.js. I've been using the EffectComposer, with the code entirely duplicated from the example page here:

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_postprocessing_ssao.html

The relevant code being:

```
var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( Engine.scene, Engine.camera );
ssaoPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
ssaoPass.renderToScreen = true;
// ...various ShaderPass setup parameters

Engine.effectComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( Engine.renderer );

Engine.effectComposer.addPass(renderPass);
Engine.effectComposer.addPass(ssaoPass);
```

The issue I have been having is that that SSAO doesn't seem to work with SkinnedMeshes. It seems to take into account the position of the meshes *before* the skinning calculations are performed.

It looks like this:

[Problem with SSAO on SkinnedMesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bhx8y.png)

Does anyone have any experience with this on the latest version? I've looked all over the place, but can't find any documentation about how to start fixing this at all.

I found mention of a fix for this in another SO post ([ThreeJS SSAO Shader w/ Skinned/Animated Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817406/threejs-ssao-shader-w-skinned-animated-models)), but the solution has been deprecated.

Thanks in advance, and happy to go into more detail if needed.

As requested, here is the complete code for the [simple demo page](http://demo.bgk.io):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/three.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/CopyShader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/EffectComposer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/MaskPass.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/RenderPass.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/ShaderPass.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/DotScreenShader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/postprocessing/SSAOShader.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="demo-container"></div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    window.doPostPro = 0;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.set(0, 200, 200);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

    clock = new THREE.Clock();

    // Setup the renderer.
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
        antialias: true
    });
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xFFFFFF );

    function setupPostProcessing() {

        // Setup render pass
        var renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );

        // Setup depth pass
        depthMaterial = new THREE.MeshDepthMaterial();
        depthMaterial.depthPacking = THREE.RGBADepthPacking;
        depthMaterial.blending = THREE.NoBlending;

        depthRenderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, {
            minFilter:      THREE.LinearFilter, 
            magFilter:      THREE.LinearFilter,
            stencilBuffer:  true
        });

        // Setup SSAO pass
        ssaoPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.SSAOShader );
        ssaoPass.renderToScreen = true;
        //ssaoPass.uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value will be set by ShaderPass
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ "tDepth" ].value = depthRenderTarget.texture;
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'size' ].value.set( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraNear' ].value = camera.near;
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'cameraFar' ].value = camera.far;
        //ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'onlyAO' ].value = ( postprocessing.renderMode == 1 );
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'aoClamp' ].value = 0.3;
        ssaoPass.uniforms[ 'lumInfluence' ].value = 0.5;

        // Add pass to effect composer
        effectComposer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer );
        effectComposer.addPass( renderPass );
        effectComposer.addPass( ssaoPass );
    };

    setupPostProcessing();

    // Load the mesh.
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load( "js/zombie.js", function( geometry, materials ) {

        var originalMaterial = materials[ 0 ];
        originalMaterial.skinning = true;

        geometry.computeVertexNormals();

        var mesh = new THREE.SkinnedMesh(geometry, originalMaterial);

        window.animMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(mesh);
        var animAction = animMixer.clipAction(geometry.animations[0]);
        animAction.play();

        scene.add(mesh);
    });

    var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xCCCCCC );
    scene.add( ambientLight );

    $("#demo-container").append( renderer.domElement );

    function render() {

        if ( doPostPro ) {

            // Render depth into depthRenderTarget
            scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
            renderer.render( scene, camera, depthRenderTarget, true );

            // Render renderPass and SSAO shaderPass
            scene.overrideMaterial = null;
            effectComposer.render();
        }
        else {

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    }

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );

        if ( window.animMixer != undefined ) {

            var deltaTime = clock.getDelta();
            animMixer.update(deltaTime);            
        }

        render();
    }

    animate();

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

        // P is pressed.
        if ( e.which == 80 ) {

            window.doPostPro = !window.doPostPro;
        }
    });

});



</script>
```

Comment: Please show your complete code and preferably link to a simple live example.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I've put together a very simple live demo here: http://demo.bgk.io/ Press P to toggle SSAO on and off. (I'll update the main post with the code too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are skinning, and using this pattern in your render loop

```
// Render depth into depthRenderTarget
scene.overrideMaterial = depthMaterial;
renderer.render( scene, camera, depthRenderTarget, true );
```

you have to make sure to set

```
depthMaterial.skinning = true;
```

Thing is, if there are other elements in the scene that are not skinned, doing so will throw errors. In which case, this may be a three.js design issue that will have to be addressed.

three.js r.77

Comment: Wonderful, thanks very much. That does work, but it does indeed throw errors with non-skinned meshes. It would be excellent if that feature were able to be added in future versions of three.js. Is there a manner in which I should bring this to anyone's attention or anything? Maybe an issue on the github page?

Comment: Yes, you can post a feature request on the three.js site.